# MongoDb query for Month comparision in loopback application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I am using MongoDB as datasource for my loopback application. In that i have to retrieve the documents for current month.

So i am tried the following:

```
app.models.aaaa.count({ $where : 'return this.Date.getMonth() == 7'}, function(err, res){
});
```

Now i want to filter based on year and userId also. How can i construct the query for that.

I tried the following:

```
app.models.aaaa.count({ $where : 'return this.Date.getMonth() == 7 && this.Date.getYear() == 2016'}, function(err, res){
    });
```

But it checks for only month..Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
[
  {
    "aaaId": "57a84a572b9a79022198c6dd",
    "bbId": "876hjg786",
    "Date": "2016-08-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    "cccc": [
      "57a1bfd0c77554fd746a538d'",
      "57a1bfebc77554fd746a538f"
    ],
    "id": "57a85e1d9841c9cb1b100f21"
  },
  {
    "aaaId": "57a84a572b9a79022198c6dd",
    "bbId": "876hjg786",
    "Date": "2016-08-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    "cccc": [
      "57a1bfd0c77554fd746a538d'",
      "57a1bfebc77554fd746a538f"
    ],
    "id": "57a85f1d1605d9f11b4d21b3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a document in your database?

Comment: can you use aggregation framework? it will be much faster.

Comment: @evilive Can you post some code for that??

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
db.myCollection.count( 
  function() { 
    return (this.Date.getMonth() == 7 && this.Date.getYear() == 2016); 
  }
);
```

Note that if you only have a `$where`, you can just write the JavaScript function as the `.count()` argument, or just the expression as a string as follows:

```
db.myCollection.count("this.Date.getMonth() == 7 && this.Date.getYear() == 2016");
```

Comment: I am receiving error `AssertionError: The where argument must be an object`

Answer (score 0):

Use [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) for project and match the docs:

```js
collection.aggregate(
  {$project: {
    month: {$month: "$Date"}, 
    year: {$year: "$Date"}
  }}, 
  {$match: {month: 8, year: 2016}}
)￼;
```

you will get something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a86cbe8357264ce0b55b2b"), "m" : 8, "y" : 2016 }
```

if you need some fields from original document just describe them in `project` stage.

Using aggregation must be much more efficient then using `where`.